# If f+g in L2 then so are f and g

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Is it true that if f+g is a function in L2(R)  then f and g must be in L2(R)?
Does it also hold true for the multiplication of f and g?

Comment: Not at all. Let $h$ not be in $L^2$ and use $h+(-h) = 0$. For multiplication, let $f = g = 1/\sqrt{x}$ on the interval $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: It is, however, true if $f,g \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. $h+ (-h) \equiv 0 \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ for any $h$ and $1_{(-\infty, 0)} \cdot 1_{(0, \infty)} \equiv 0 \in L^2(\mathbb R)$.